# digitalocean centos 8.2 nginx+php+mysql+phpmyadmin installed, but ip/phpmyadmin dont working

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, centos8

digitalocean centos 8.2 nginx+php+mysql+phpmyadmin installed, but ip/phpmyadmin dont working. What parameters should I change?

ip/phpmyadmin

404 not found

Comment: How have you installed phpMyAdmin? Did you download the source and uncompress it? If so, to where have you uncompressed it? Have you used a package manager? In that case, which from which repository is it installed? Which phpMyAdmin version is it?

Answer (score 0):

The phpMyAdmin package is not available as an RPM package in OS repositories for CentOS 8. So, we will download the archive from the official website.

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.1/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages.tar.gz
```

Install phpMyAdmin using the following command.

```
sudo tar -zxvf phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages.tar.gz
```

Move the phpMyAdmin directory as shown below:

```
sudo mv phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

Copy the sample configuration file.

```
sudo cp -pr /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.sample.inc.php /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

Edit the configuration file and add the blowfish secret.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

Generate blowfish secret and update the secret in the below line.

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

to

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'w/Syf.ficLZSekNkphWRffR8rgdckD7N';
```

To generate new blowfish secret, simply hit this https://phpsolved.com/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator/?g=5f00161dabd31

Next, Import the create_tables.sql to create new tables for phpMyAdmin.

```
mysql < /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/sql/create_tables.sql -u root -p
```

Create a virtual host file named phpMyAdmin.conf in the /etc/nginx/conf.d.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Add the following making changes to the domain name. You can replace it with your own domain name or your server's IP Address.

```
server {
listen 80;
   server_name phpmyadmin.cloudwaferlabs.com;
   root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;

   location / {
      index index.php;
   }

## Images and static content is treated different
   location ~*             ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
  access_log off;
  expires 30d;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
   }

   location ~ /(libraries|setup/frames|setup/libs) {
      deny all;
      return 404;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
}
```

now u can check your url

Comment: Can I replace ip / phpmyadmin with phpmyadmin.cloudwaferlabs.com?

Comment: i don't know what u mean but u can secure your phpmyadmin by moving it to another pather
mv phpmyadmin yourNewPath 
and u can follow this article on digital ocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04)